# How to allow the user to resize an image in a JEditorPane by using arrows in the border's image

Tags: java, swing

I have a JEditorPane with custom HTMLFactory which include some images. I want to let the user to resize the image with some arrows in the border of the image.
I'm using a custom view for resizing the image.

When I resize an image, the paint method is getting executed indefinitely and make me loose the positions of the images in the document.

Do you have some suggestions please ?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Use an `ActionListener` on a (set of) `JButton`(s). The `ActionListener` will set the size of the container the image is in, and repaint. I recommend looking up how to use `ActionListeners` and how to paint / repaint images within `JPanels`.

Comment: But how to add JPanels to JEditorPane while using a HTMLEditorKit ?

Comment: You need to say these things in your post if you expect people to know them. I have no experience with it, but I would expect it to work like any other Java container. Add the `JPanel` to the `JEditorPane`. If that doesn't work, consider why you're using a `JEditorPane` to display an image.